# Hippo CMS & Jetspeed

Tags: java, content-management-system, portal, hippocms

I'm looking at a solution to manage my content between a website & intranet and was playing with Hippo CMS in combination with Jetspeed. It looks good, bus does anybody have any experience with this combination? And where do you shop for more portlets?

Answer (score 3):

I have some experience with this solution. Hippo introduced a completely rewritten version of their CMS beginning this year. This new version 7 eventually will get all features available in the previous version, but currently that is not the case (yet). However, the rewrite also made the CMS much more flexible and extensible. 
They provide a toolkit for developing websites using the Hippo CMS as backend. This toolkit (called HST2) produces fairly generic components, since they can easily be converted to portlets which can be deployed on a Jetspeed portal (in fact, you only have to change one build parameter to get this working). Hippo also has an integrated solution in their product line-up called Hippo Portal. However, this is based on an old version of Hippo CMS and Jetspeed and will eventually be deprecated (I suppose).

Jetspeed is a nice portal. Recently version 2.2.0 was released. This version implements the Portal 2.0 spec, and as such can run all portlets which are conforming to this spec. There is no one location where you can get Jetspeed-specific portlets, but searching on the internet will probably give you some results (as said, Portlets doesn't have to be Jetspeed specific, if they implement the Portlet 2.0 spec (JSR-286) they will run on Jetspeed).

It is also pretty easy to create your own portlets. We use Spring Portlet MVC for this task, making the development of a portlet almost as easy as developing a generic Spring MVC app.